# How to get years old and residual days from two dates in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two dates: 1860-07-21 and 1920-04-23.
With this portion of query I get the total of days between the dates:

```
DATEDIFF(str_to_date(concat(Right(FirstTime,2),"-", Mid(FirstTime,6,2),"-",Left(FirstTime,4)),'%d-%m-%Y'), str_to_date(concat(Right(Born,2),"-", Mid(Born,6,2),"-",Left(Born,4)),'%d-%m-%Y')) as Days
```

The result is 21825 days. How should I modify the query portion above to get 59 years and 277 days?

Comment: If `FirstTime`, `Born` store date values, then you should be using the `DATE` data type for these fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
SELECT

  @yearsDiff:=(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    YEAR,
    str_to_date(concat(Right(FirstTime,2),'-', Mid(FirstTime,6,2),'-',Left(FirstTime,4)),'%d-%m-%Y'),
    str_to_date(concat(Right(Born,2),'-', Mid(Born,6,2),'-',Left(Born,4)),'%d-%m-%Y')
  )) as YEARS,

  TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    DAY,
    DATE_ADD(str_to_date(concat(Right(FirstTime,2),'-', Mid(FirstTime,6,2),'-',Left(FirstTime,4)),'%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL @yearsDiff YEAR),
    str_to_date(concat(Right(Born,2),'-', Mid(Born,6,2),'-',Left(Born,4)),'%d-%m-%Y')
  ) as DAYS

FROM (SELECT '1860-07-21' AS FirstTime, '1920-04-23' AS Born) AS t
```

Comment: I get a noisy "-" (minus) before the number, and the second field gets the total days (21825) instead of 277 residual days.

Comment: did it help you?